# M Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 5 custom title on home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial: the exercises at the end of chapter 5 involve simplifying RSpec tests.

5.37 ( http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-layout_exercises ) defines several test for the home page.
In the file spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
  .
  .
  .
  .
    it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
      full_title("").should_not =~ /\|/
    end
  end
end
```

For this test to pass, I need to have the Home page title display:
"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
And not "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home"

But, the tutorial doesn't walk me through how to code that change.

Here's what I've tried:

In app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:

1. Remove:

   `<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>`

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  Edit the  tag to:

```
<title>
 <% if :title
  full_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | " && yield(:title)
 else
  full_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end %>
 <%= print full_title %>
</title>
```

And other variations my noob brain could muster.
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

If the page has no title provided, return "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

If there is a title provided, return "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | #PageTitle"

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: As a quick comment, you should set some value @full_title = ___ in the controller.

Then you can do additional conditioning (still in the controller), for instance, if there's a title you can concat the bar and the title.

Comment: @wrhall I appreciate that. I have tried @full_title and :full_title to no avail. I've also tried `<%= yield(@full_title) %>` instead of `<%= print @full_title %>`

Comment: Any reason why you rolledback an edit that improved your post?

Comment: If I felt that your edits improved the grammar or layout of the post, I would have accepted them.

Comment: @Chiperific I'm currently "cleaning up" all posts tagged with the `[home]` tag (in preparation for burnination), which, according to policy, requires me to fix/improve *all* parts of the post...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-title_helper

Just call the method inside your view.
So it should be something like
`<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>`
as he says.

Comment: Wow. I searched back through chapters 3 and 4 and missed this somehow. Thank you so much!