# Ch 8 Michael Hartl's RoR's tutorial No Method Error: Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I keep getting the the error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `full_title'.

In my test/integration/site_layout_test.rb file, I have the following code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    test "layout links" do
        get root_path   
        assert_template 'static_pages/home'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
        get signup_path
        assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
    end
end
```

When I remove `assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")` and run Guard, the test is green, but when I put it back, I get the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731391/m-hartls-ruby-on-rails-tutorial-chapter-5-custom-title-on-home-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the full_title function defined in app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis. If a page doesn't provide a
  # title, just use the base title.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = Rails.application.config.web_app_name
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " - " + base_title
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! - as you suggested, I looked at this. It was defined, but to double check I copied the code straight from the book - I still get the error.

Comment: If you're following the tutorial, this test should't be doing checking the title. Delete that line and the test correctly checks the links. There is a test to check the titles in test\controllers\static_pages_controller_test.rb

If you wish to have your layout links test also test the title, there are two problems. The first is that the test does not know about full_title, which is defined in module ApplicationHelper. You'd have to include it. The second problem is that the test gets the root_path, but is checking a title of "Sign Up" That's probably not the right title for the home page.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I copy/pasted the full_title method from application_helper.rb to test_helper.rb, and it worked after that. Hope that helps!